# How to get Key based on specified Value from nested dictionary and tuple

Tags: python, dictionary, tuples, statsmodels

I am statsmodels function in Python which returns a nested dictionary and tuples within. I would like to find the primary Key value based on a specific value but I can't seem to get to it because the dictionary is multi nested with what looks tuples within.

The dictionary is called = testresult it returns the value 0.06066703605850239 as output. I want map this back to the high level key it relates to but trying something likes this returns "key doesn't exist", i.e the value is not found:

```
def GetKey(val):
   for key, value in testresult.items():
      if val == value:
         return key
      return "key doesn't exist"
print(GetKey(0.06066703605850239))
```

The actual output from the dictionary is below. Only showing the first three keys. All I am after is the high level key mapping back to the valye which here is KEY 2, i.e the match is in this line
"'ssr_chi2test': (5.604709583431151, 0.06066703605850239, 2)" which maps back to key 2.

testresult Output:

```
{1: ({'ssr_ftest': (2.8419033957600366, 0.09231901211324843, 645.0, 1),
   'ssr_chi2test': (2.8551215510891534, 0.09108335476517923, 1),
   'lrtest': (2.84885005932847, 0.09143931932517006, 1),
   'params_ftest': (2.8419033957602227, 0.09231901211323784, 645.0, 1.0)},
  [<statsmodels.regression.linear_model.RegressionResultsWrapper at 0x1570bc161c8>,
   <statsmodels.regression.linear_model.RegressionResultsWrapper at 0x1570b993d08>,
   array([[0., 1., 0.]])]),
 2: ({'ssr_ftest': (2.780698263186089, 0.06274205544426932, 642.0, 2),
   'ssr_chi2test': (5.604709583431151, 0.06066703605850239, 2),
   'lrtest': (5.580573162296787, 0.061403614274963624, 2),
   'params_ftest': (2.780698263186609, 0.0627420554442373, 642.0, 2.0)},
  [<statsmodels.regression.linear_model.RegressionResultsWrapper at 0x1570bc78cc8>,
   <statsmodels.regression.linear_model.RegressionResultsWrapper at 0x1570bc6c448>,
   array([[0., 0., 1., 0., 0.],
          [0., 0., 0., 1., 0.]])]),
 3: ({'ssr_ftest': (2.1251237213749516, 0.09582281329876917, 639.0, 3),
   'ssr_chi2test': (6.445210910836708, 0.09184847479199953, 3),
   'lrtest': (6.4132709026562225, 0.09314635939984041, 3),
   'params_ftest': (2.125123721374674, 0.09582281329880636, 639.0, 3.0)},
  [<statsmodels.regression.linear_model.RegressionResultsWrapper at 0x1570bc60d48>,
   <statsmodels.regression.linear_model.RegressionResultsWrapper at 0x1570bc60e88>,
   array([[0., 0., 0., 1., 0., 0., 0.],
          [0., 0., 0., 0., 1., 0., 0.],
          [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 1., 0.]])])
```

I've been really struggling with this and spent lots of time on it trying to work it out so any help would be really useful and time saving. I am using Python 3.7.

Thanks

Lucas

Answer (score 0):

You need to get to the proper element

```py
def GetKey(val):
    for key, value in testresult.items():
        for tpl in value[0].values():
            if val in tpl:
                return key
    return "key doesn't exist"

print(GetKey(0.06066703605850239))
```

```
2
```

Comment: Thanks. This is exactly what I wanted!